# How do my users "opt in" to iTunesConnect crashes?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

iTunesConnect shows a crash in my app under App Analytics.

But Crashes shows "not enough data" with "Opt in Only". How do my clients opt-in to upload crash reports?

Answer (score 4):

### For iOS 8 and 9

Go to Settings > Privacy > Diagnostics & Usage, and select Automatically Send or Don't Send.

### For iOS 10 - 10.2

Settings > Privacy > Diagnostics & Usage and select Automatically Send or Don't Send.

### For iOS 10.3+

Settings > Privacy, scroll down and tap Analytics. Then tap Share iPhone & Watch Analytics.

Here is Apple's Support Site with this information https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202100

Answer (score 1):

I think iOS asks users to share crash data with developers when the user sets up a new iOS device. Same place where it asks to enable siri, add fingerprints, etc. You can also enable/disable it in Settings -> Privacy -> Diagnostics & Usage -> Share with App Developers.

Comment: This has changed with newer versions of iOS I have submitted a new answer that contains the updated paths for iOS 10+ Thank you for your answer which works in iOS 8 and 9 :)